# AnyValue in Swift Dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I'd like to represent a dictionary like this:

```
[
   angles: [first: 1.2, second: 2.2],
   other: 3
]
```

Is this possible in iOS Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use strings as keys, but otherwise *yes* -- you can declare it explicitly as a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary:

```
let dict: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "angles": ["first": 1.2, "second": 2.2],
    "other": 3
]
```

or let type inference decide it's an `NSDictionary`:

```
let dict = [
    "angles": ["first": 1.2, "second": 2.2],
    "other": 3
]
```

Note that you'll have plenty of hassles dealing with this data structure later - if possible define a struct that describes your data instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was using strings as keys, I was just In a hurry when I posted the question. You answered by using AnyObject as the value type.

Comment: Note that numbers and arrays are not objects in Swift. This relies on the bridging in `Foundation`. If you don't import Foundation it won't work.

Comment: That's a good point - if you haven't included Foundation you would need to declare the dictionary as `[String: Any]`, which is even more of a mess to deal with.